# Xampp Virtualhost

Tags: wordpress, apache, xampp, vhosts

I am configuring a XAMPP Apache server to work with wordpress multisites and do not understand the following directive:

"VirtualDocumentRoot "C:/xampp/www/%-2/sub/%-3"

what is the purpose of **%-2** and **%-3** ?

Forgive the basic nature of my question but I can't seem to understand the mechanics of these two terms. Can anyone point me to where this notation might be explained?

Thanks in advance for any help or direction

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer,

this is known as "Directory Name Interpolation"

Apache explains this here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html

I've pasted an excerpt:

> Directory Name Interpolation
>
> All the directives in this module interpolate a string into a
> pathname. The interpolated string (henceforth called the "name") may
> be either the server name (see the UseCanonicalName directive for
> details on how this is determined) or the IP address of the virtual
> host on the server in dotted-quad format. The interpolation is
> controlled by specifiers inspired by printf which have a number of
> formats: %%   insert a % %p   insert the port number of the virtual host
> %N.M  insert (part of) the name
>
> N and M are used to specify substrings of the name. N selects from the
> dot-separated components of the name, and M selects characters within
> whatever N has selected. M is optional and defaults to zero if it
> isn't present; the dot must be present if and only if M is present.
> The interpretation is as follows:
> 0     the whole name
> 1     the first part
> 2     the second part
> -1    the last part
> -2    the penultimate part 2+     the second and all subsequent parts
> -2+   the penultimate and all preceding parts 1+ and -1+  the same as 0
>
> If N or M is greater than the number of parts available a single
> underscore is interpolated.